# What does $ div_xf $ denote?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I was reading something. then I came across this equation,
 \begin{equation}
\ u_t= a\Delta u+div_x f+h,  
\ ~~\  
\end{equation} 
and stumbled across this notation  $ div_xf $. What does this denotion mean?

Answer (score 2):

If $f: \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ then $\mathrm{div}_x f(x,t) = \nabla_x \cdot f = \partial_{x_1}f(x,t) + \dots + \partial_{x_n}f(x,t) $, is the *divergence operator* with respect to $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, i.e. the sum of the first partial derivatives w.r.t. $x_1, \dots, x_n$.